# Limit proof using $\epsilon-N$ proof, Notation explanation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What does the notation $N>\max\{100, 2/\epsilon\}$ differ from $N>\max\{2/\epsilon,100\}$ ? For example

Problem 1. Prove $\lim (1/n-100) =0$ as $n\to\infty$. The answer to this one is $N>\max\{400,2/\epsilon\}$

Problem 2. Prove $\lim n/(n^2-2n-40)=0$ as $n\to\infty$. The answer here is $N>\max\{2/\epsilon, 100\}$

Can someone please explain how to get to that? What is the difference?

Comment: it is difficult to comment on your notation if you have not formatted it correctly

Comment: please read your post again and correct all typos. I think there are more differences then intended.

Comment: They are the same, just like $1+2$ and $2+1$ are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to do my best here, starting with the notation I think you meant:

**Problem 1.** Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n-100} =0$. The answer to this one is N>max{400,2/ε}

Let $\epsilon>0$. We need to show that there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n>N$ imply that $|\frac{1}{n-100}|<\epsilon$.

Consider any $N$ so that $N>\max\{400,\frac{2}{\epsilon}\}$... *you need to show that this $N$ works*

In problem 2, the notation is precisely the same, and they really mean the same thing.

If it's the order swap that is bothering you, remember that the order is unspecified in set notation, and so the max function does not depend at all on whether $2/\epsilon$ or $100$ comes first.

Comment: Thank you! Also, could you explain where did the 400 come from? in the first solution? Wouldn't 200 work too?

Comment: why do you say that? These are details that should be included in your question, you should show what you've done.

Answer (score 2):

These are the exact same. Sets are not ordered, and you are taking the maximum out of elements in a set, {$\epsilon/2,100$}